# How do I provide Admin username and password to ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap

Typically, we configure a vanilla LdapAuthenticationProvider with a Dn and a password.

```
auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .contextSource()
        .url(env.getProperty("spring.ldap.urls") + "/" + env.getProperty("spring.ldap.base"))
        .managerDn(env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn") + "," + env.getProperty("spring.ldap.base"))
        .managerPassword(env.getProperty("spring.ldap.password"))
```

How should I go about achieving a similar configuration with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ?

Snippet of my current progress:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.org",
                "ldap://activedirectory-url:389");
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
    }

}
```

I'm scratching my head about how to implement the same functionality with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. I have searched high and low but I'm at a loss on how to replicate the previous configuration with the Active Directory.